# Insert rows into remote and local database mysql

Tags: php, mysql, insert, local

I have a project where im trying to INSERT a couple of values into 2 databases simultaniously. Database1 is local and database2 is on a remote server. I have tried working with this but i can't seem to insert the rows when using this code.
Kind of new to php/mysql, but i would like to get some help understanding why this syntax doesnt work.

Underneath you'll find a piece of the connecting and (trying) inserting into the DBB's

```
$local = mysql_connect("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword");
$remote = mysql_connect("externalhost", "dbuser", "dbpassword");
$dbase1 = mysql_select_db("dbname", $local) or die(mysql_error());
$dbase2 = mysql_select_db("dbname", $remote) or die(mysql_error());


mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(value1,value2,value3)                             

VALUES('test','test','test')",$dbase1);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableExt(value1,value2,value3,value4,value5)                             

VALUES('test','test','test','test','test')",$dbase2);
```

Comment: you have given hostname instead of db name in `mysql_select_db` and instead of username u have given dbname in `mysql_connect`

Comment: Made an typ error unfortunately, corrected it. But still not able to INSERT with the correct dbname and username

Comment: you can check with two local db connection if work properly then there is prob with remote conn.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table(value1,value2,value3) VALUES('test','test','test')",$local);
```

http://php.net/mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting within the Cpanel to allowed remote conection or not. By default it is inactive. Have you givent the permission in to the Cpanel?

Comment: The remote connection is allowed